# ViewModel validation with nested models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, viewmodel

My model contains two objects (Reminders and Users). Each reminder is associated with one user.

```
public class Reminder
    {
    [DisplayName("Subject")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0}: error message.")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "{0}: error message.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Supervisor")]
    public User DepartmentSupervisor { get; set; }
    }

public class User 
    {
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0}: error message.")]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "{0}: lerror message.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0}: error message.")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage="Not valid.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

I've defined a viewmodel I use to pass data to my view:

```
public class RemindersViewModel
    {
        public RemindersViewModel()
        {
            this.Supervisors = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        public Models.Reminder Reminder { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Supervisors { get; set; }
    }
```

Supervisors is a list of Users (SelectListItem) I use to render a combo.
When I submit the form the controller rebinds the object Reminder:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, Models.Reminder Reminder)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    // PROBLEM.
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and I have my reminder associated with the choosen user (username) but, since I don't need to show the email in the dropdown, the binding can't fill the field, cause it doesn't exists in my form. 
In the validation process I get an error cause it tries to validate the User model, which is not what I really want. 
What's the best approach dealing with nested models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using view models? They include only the properties your view requires and the validation for this particular view. So if your view doesn't require an email you write a view model without an email and the validation passes great. Then inside your controller action you map this view model to the corresponding domain model. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is a great tool for this job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Darin. As far as I can understand you suggest to "flatten" my viewmodel?! My class remider would have a DepartmentSupervisor property which is not of type User ... is that right? Do you have any examples?

Comment: @vandalo, not necessarily flatten. So you might have a `ReminderViewModel` and a `UserViewModel` each containing only the properties that you would be working with in this particular view. The ReminderViewModel will then have a property of type UserViewModel.

Comment: I am starting to understand.The think is I've got my domain (entities) classes. Then I've created some intermediate classes (reminder, user, etc) with validation rules and I nest these classes in my ViewModel. For what I can understand I should get rid of the intermediate class and just have entities (domain) and viewmodels. Is it right?

Comment: @vandalo, yes exactly. You have your domain classes which cannot be modified. They represent your business logic. Then according to the requirements of the view you are designing you define view model classes. And the controller would perform the mapping between your domain models and the view models.